# Can mining rig be used for blender rendering?

Tags: rendering, hardware

I have seen some mining rig with 6 gpu in one motherboard, can you use that for rendering?

edit: http://www.coinminingrigs.com/how-to-build-a-6-gpu-mining-rig/

1x 1200 Watt Power Supply

1x 6 GPU Motherboard

1x Skylake Dual Core CPU

1x 4 GB RAM (system memory)

6x Nvidia GTX 1070 GPU’s (6 of these, I like EVGA and Gigabyte)
1x USB Riser Cables (6 pack)

1x Solid State Drive (for OS / mining software)

1x Custom Mining Case

heres what it looks like
[image: 6 gpu in one motherboard, can you use that for rendering?]

Comment: What kind of GPUs and Rig? You need more details before anyone can help you.

Comment: What is a "mining rig"? Where have you seen this? What specs does it have? WHat jobs will it be rendering? With which software? What render engine?

Comment: simple answer is **yes**.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos that is a machine for "mining" bitcoins.

Comment: Oh I see thanks for the clarification, for a moment there I though he just miss-typed "mini-rig" as in some sort of small computer case

Comment: May be you won't be able to render with your minig rig, because it uses 1X risers for the GPU, which may not provide sufficient through put. Can anyone comment if he/she know answer to this limitation.

Answer (score 4):

I went out and purchased a P106-90 video card for about $70.
The card showed up properly on windows 10 and automatically installed the drivers.

[image]

Blender automatically detected the card

[image]

And it cut renders down from

1:32 to 49 seconds

Which means I was able to cut my render times in half.

[image]

Additionally, searching the blender benchmark data shows benchmarks from users with the cards p106-90 and p106-100

https://opendata.blender.org/benchmarks/query/?device_name=P106-090&device_type=CUDA

Note: According to some sources, the eevee render only uses the first gpu, so its likely adding a second gpu won't increase the speed of previews. Only Cycles renderer is able to use multiple GPUs.

Also these cards can only be leveraged for blender, since nvidia blocks the ability to use these cards for video games.

### Additional information

- Motherboard: ECS A885GM-A2
- Windows 10 Home

Comment: Finally some one tried it (all it takes is some facts to dispel the myths)!

Answer (score 3):

If the GPUs supports either CUDA or OpenCL it will most likely work.

Check https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html for more info about Blender/Cycles GPU rendering.

Answer (score 2):

The below is from official Blender Documentation.

**Can multiple GPUs be used for rendering?**

Yes, go to User Preferences -> System -> Compute Device Panel, and configure it as you desire.

**Would multiple GPUs increase available memory?**

No, each GPU can only access its own memory.

Source: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, however these gpus have custom firmware that prevent the cards from being used for anything besides mining.

People on the following forms have had mixed results using them for gaming.

- https://www.reddit.com/r/blender/comments/a5pb4z/anyone_know_whether_the_nvidia_gtx_1060_p106_a/
- https://www.blendernation.com/2019/02/22/headless-mining-card-gpu-106-100-as-a-graphics-cards/

This user in particular reports success using the cards with blender

- https://blenderartists.org/t/solved-blender-ubuntu-not-detecting-new-gpu-after-switch/1150099

They did have to reset blender to *forget* previous video cards that were used.

```
blender -b --python-console              # Start python console
>> import bpy
>> bpy.ops.wm.read_factory_settings()    # Load factory settings
>> bpy.ops.wm.save_userpref()            # Save factory settings
```

#### Additional information

- https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-set-gpu-preferences-remotely/1147766/12

Additional users have reported mixed results depending on what graphics driver version they are using. Nvidia is actively trying to prevent people from using these cards so even if you do get it working, there is no guarantee that it will work after additional updates

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=08eeXcIeM14